# Linear Gradient at an angle

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a "beam" of white light like the following image using linear background gradients:

[image]

Angle of the gradient needs to be at 100 degrees. I've attempted to create this via jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/gqn8tv69/

CSS:

```
.skeleton-9r7r1v3dh92:empty {box-sizing: content-box; height: 400px; background-color: #000000; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-image: linear-gradient( 100deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.5) 20%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.5) 80%, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 0% );background-repeat: repeat-y;background-size: 100px 400px;background-position: 50% 0}
```

But everything I try either side has a dramatic cut. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
.box {
  background:linear-gradient(100deg,#000 42%,#fff 48% 52%,#000 58%);
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or like below for a fixed size:

```css
.box {
  background:linear-gradient(100deg,#000 calc(50% - 50px),#fff,#000 calc(50% + 50px));
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this "beam" using [Colorzilla gradient editor](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), you can adjust the percentages or use the [permalink](https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#0a0809+0,0a0e0a+44,ffffff+49,000000+53,000000+100) to the gradient :

```css
.gradient {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#0a0809+0,0a0e0a+44,ffffff+49,000000+53,000000+100 */
  background: #0a0809; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #0a0809 0%, #0a0e0a 44%, #ffffff 49%, #000000 53%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #0a0809 0%,#0a0e0a 44%,#ffffff 49%,#000000 53%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #0a0809 0%,#0a0e0a 44%,#ffffff 49%,#000000 53%,#000000 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0a0809', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```